# How can you conditionally add inner joins to a select statement?

Tags: sql, if-statement, inner-join

I have a variable that I need to check to see what the value is and I need to do an inner join to different tables based on what that value is. Here's an example of what I'm asking...

```
Declare @category nvarchar(100)

select *  
from tableA a  
if (@category = 'all)  
begin  
    inner join tableB b on b.ID = a.ID  
end  
else if (@category = 'open')  
begin  
    inner join tableC c on c.ID = a.ID  
end
```

UPDATE: I think I should have included that I'm using Common Table Expressions and I've tried using dynamic sql, and even doing if statements to call different CTE's, but it seems that CTE's do not like anything but a simple select statement.

Thanks for any advice I can get on this.

Comment: Are you considering the usage of a parameterized stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is:

```
select * 
from tableA a 
inner join tableB b on b.ID = a.ID
where @category = 'all'
union all
select * 
from tableA a 
inner join tableC c on c.ID = a.ID  
where @category = 'open'
```

Comment: +1 That's correct, but will only work if the fieldset `tableA.*+tableB.*` has the same columns, same types of `tableA.*+tableC.*`. What I mean is that a `union` only work on two or more datasets with same column types

Comment: thanks, this one worked. I'm just calling each CTE with a union and where @category = "..."

Comment: @Jose good point, I am assuming schemas are the same in tableB and tableC;

Answer (score 0):

Make your whole query a varchar, then use dynamic execution.

```
declare @sqltorun as varchar(max)
set @sqltorun = 'select *  from tableA a '
if(@Category=='a')
@sqltorun = @sqltorun + 'inner join tableB b on b.ID = a.ID   '
else
@sqltorun = @sqltorun + 'inner join tableB b on b.ID = a.ID '
sp_executesql @sqltorun
```